# Recognizing and displaying 360 degree images in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, jpeg

I've got some 360 degree images like [this](https://www.flickr.com/photos/145636054@N04/31204161034/in/pool-360degrees/) one that I'd like to embed in a website. I've been looking but haven't found what plugin or (possibly) HTML5 methods are used to embed and play these as panoramas.

Is there a way to detect these jpg images (as opposed to "standard" jpgs) and display them as 360 views? If you click the download button and view the source image, you'll see what I mean about how the filetype is a normal jpg.

[image]

I'd like to be able to recognize these and play the "player" while not doing the same for non-360 images.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes You can use A-frame which is based on threejs for VR and 360 image use.
simply put in your head tag script reference to A-frame.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

and in your body: basically the a-sky takes whatever image source you give it and wraps that around the view (if the pic source isn't 360 image it will look wrong).

```
 <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-sky src="yourpicpath.jpg"></a-sky>
    </a-scene> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**HTML :**

```
<br>jQuery Pan-o-matic
<br>
<br>
<div class="pan-wrap pan0"></div>
<br>
<div class="pan-wrap pan1"></div>
<br>
<div class="pan-wrap pan2"></div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
$('.pan-wrap').append('<div class="play">play</div>');

var hoverInterval;

function doStuff() {
  $(this).animate({
    'background-position-x': '+=5%',
  }, 250, 'linear');
}

$(function() {
  $('.pan-wrap').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).empty();
      hoverInterval = setInterval($.proxy(doStuff, this), 250);
    },
    function() {
      // stop calling doStuff
      $(this).append('<div class="play">play</div>');
      clearInterval(hoverInterval);
      $('this').animate({
        'background-position-x': '+=5%',
      }, 1000, 'easeOutQuint');
    });
});
```

**CSS :**

```
body {
  background: rgb(240, 205, 97);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pan0 {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/suKT3.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.pan1 {
  background: url('http://kthornbloom.com/public/pan.jpg');
}

.pan2 {
  background: url('http://kthornbloom.com/public/pan2.jpg');
}

.pan-wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(209, 126, 20);
  cursor: e-resize;
}

.play {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.71);
  height: 25px;
  width: 75px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -34px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**JSFiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/k7thyvon/

Note : Don't forget to inclue jquery.easing.1.3.js to your page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's hosted VR view https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview. As an example, you can include the following in your web page:

```
<iframe width="100%"
    height="300px"
    allowfullscreen
    frameborder="0"
    src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&
    is_stereo=true">
</iframe>
```

You can also host the VR view yourself. Download the code from https://github.com/googlevr/vrview and host it somewhere with public access. If you keep it within a folder called **“360view”** on your server, then you will be able to access it at `//yourdomain.com/360view/?image=examples/coral.jpg&is_stereo=true`
Here's an example:

```html
<iframe width="100%"
 height="300px"
 allowfullscreen
 frameborder="0"
 src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/index.html?image=//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/coral.jpg&
 is_stereo=true">
</iframe>
```

Or test it in the plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/tSUJdntHoshfi38HSxzL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Refer this 
You can embed 360° photos and videos into a website using VR View

[Google VR view web](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/web/vrview-web)